# Eclipse keyword highlighting in in my own text editor

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I made a simple text editor in eclipse to which I added some simple WordRule based syntax highlighting to highlight the language keywords. The problem is that when a keyword is part of an identifier (eg. "import" is part of "extra_import"), then "import" is highlighted in "extra_import". How can I stop eclipse to highlight a a keyword if it is only a sub string of another string?

Anlther question; is there a regular expression based IRule?

What is the purpose of WhitespaceRule? White spaces are usually not highlighted.

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). That makes implementation of domain specific languages much easier than implementing the whole editor model of Eclipse from scratch.

Comment: Now at the end of development, it is not an option. Syntax highlighting is the final touch.